# Maintain display: none through all clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that has five "form-group container-fluid" on it and I am splitting them so that the top two show on one page - div:nth-child(-n+2) - and the bottom three - div:nth-child(n+3) show on a separate page. When the pages open they look perfect but when an element is clicked the page shows all five containers again. The basic scripts which work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Show only the first two containers
$("div[id$=RadAjaxPanel1] > div > div > div:nth-child(n+3)").css("display","none");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Show only the last three containers
$("div[id$=RadAjaxPanel1] > div > div > div:nth-child(-n+2)").css("display","none");
</script>
```

Which show correctly on inspection as:

```
<div class="form-group container-fluid" style="display: none;"></div>
```

I have tried many ways to add a function that maintains the same style throughout page changes and have not been successful. There are signup buttons on the pages which cause popup windows. When a button is clicked the style="display: none; is removed. Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**
After the div#id there is a comment added after clicking on the signup button:

```
<!-- 2020.1.114.45 -->
```

This seems to indicate the change on the page. Is it possible to use this in the script? After clicking a button a popup sign up form comes up. The button js selector is:

```
document.querySelector("#ctl05_ctl05_RadGrid2_ctl00_ctl06_gbcsignUp")
```

The the popup form:

```
onkeypress=javascript:return WebForm_button(event, "id#save')
```

I would be happy to know the **correct language for searching** too. I will keep searching for the answer but I have run out of ideas and knowledge for what to search.

Comment: My guess is that the DOM structure is changing and so the structure you're targeting is no longer valid.  One way around this would be to add a class to the elements themselves instead of relying on the DOM structure around those elements.  Then target that class.

Comment: The page is generated by a module that I am unable to access. Can I still add a class to the elements? I spent several hours trying to see how the DOM structure changed but couldn't identify the changes. My first thought was to write a second script that covered the different structure.

Comment: Can you target the `form-group container-fluid` classes that are already assigned?

Comment: I will try that. I also was wondering if .find would work for the specified nth-childs. I know this is possible! There is a solution...

Comment: What is the click event doing? Can you post the JS for that? Do you have access to edit that code?

Comment: @BadHorsie the click brings up a popup window to sign up. The js selector for the button is document.querySelector("#ctl05_ctl05_RadGrid2_ctl00_ctl06_gbcsignUp"). Then for the form it is, onkeypress=javascript:return WebForm_button(event, "id#save')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CSS instead of javascript as it will keep the style of the page through clicks.

```
<style>
// Show only the last three containers
[id$='RadAjaxPanel1'] > div > div > div:nth-child(-n+2) {
display: none;
}
// Show only the first two containers
[id$='RadAjaxPanel1'] > div > div > div:nth-child(n+3) {
display: none;
}
</style>
```